# Operators to overload when using STL list container?

Tags: c++, list, stl

I am trying to research which operators of a user-defined type need to be overloaded if I'm using that type in the STL list.

It seems like I at least need the comparison operators for sort() and remove() functionality.

I have been unable to find a clear description of any/all necessary operator overloading in the documentation for the template on websites like cplusplus.com. Does this mean that the list template does not require my class to have operators overloaded? If so, how is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You only need the operators that you call indirectly. You don't need `operator<` until you call `list.sort`.

That said, other operators that you *may* want are the copy constructor, assignment, move operator, and default constructor. Specializing `std::swap` could also be useful.